# Sort array of negative integers and find pair of Larger integer irrespective of sign

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array of integers as shown in the below code. I have to find pair of largest numbers in the array. But there is a small twist.

Please see the below code and output.

```
public class ArraySort {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    int[] a = { -9, -2, -10, -1, -4 };
    int[] b = null;
    int n = a.length;
    int temp = 0;
    int k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
            if (a[i] > a[j]) {
                temp = a[i];
                a[i] = a[j];
                a[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Ascending Order:");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        System.out.print(a[i] + ",");
    }

    System.out.println("\nPair of larger numbers");

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (k < 2) {
            if (a[i] > a[n - 1 - i]) {
                System.out.println(a[i]);

            } else {
                System.out.println(a[n-1-i]);
            }
        }
        k++;
    }
  }

}
```

The output of which is displayed as

```
Ascending Order:
```

-10,-9,-4,-2,-1,
Pair of larger numbers
-1
-2

But instead of displaying the largest number as -1,-2. i have to display  -10 and -9. the comparison should be without minus sign even though the array contains negative value.

Comment: use `Math.abs(...)` to get the absolute value

Comment: Is there any way to do without using Math.abs() method??

Comment: Take the smaller values then... you said you only have negative value. _I Vote to close since this is unlikely this problem could help someone in the future_

Comment: Please do explain what you have against `Math.abs()`.

Comment: `a[i] = a[i] < 0 ? -a[i] : a[i];`

Comment: Yes ...What if i have to use same code for mix of integers.. i.e. if my array has both negative and positive values.

Comment: Thanks ..much helpful comment.. :)

Comment: If you can't use `Math.abs()`, just open the source of `Math.abs()` and copy it into your code, just like what @Lino suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
   a[i] = Math.abs(a[i]);
}
```

This would convert the numbers to positive. Or you can follow what JF said. But that approach won't work if some of them are positive.

Answer (score 1):

If all your integers are negative, why not just display the *smallest* two integers?

Comment: Actually I may include some positive numbers as well in the same array. That time also it should work seamlessly...

Answer (score 1):

For the task to be meaningful ("difficult") the array should possibly contain both negative and positive numbers.

The candidates for *absolute* largest numbers reside either at the beginning or end of the array:

```
-13a, -7, -3, -2, -1, 9, 10b
-10b, -7, -3, -2, -1, 9, 13a
-13a, -11b, -3, -2, -1, 9, 10
-8, -7, -3, -2, -1, 9b, 13a
```

So you probably got two indices in one loop, one from the beginning, one from the end. No overlap (for -2, 4).

As this is home work, good luck.